# Parallel for loop to process regions of a binary image (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, image-processing, parallel-processing, binary-image

I need to parallelize one single MATLAB loop. What my code essentially does is to sequentially watershed segment each extracted binary object (that are already stored in a binary mask `bw`) that exceeds a certain threshold in size into smaller pieces. After the segmentation, I want to replace each binary chunk with its segmented pieces, but the code is giving me the errors:

- "The PARFOR loop cannot run due to the way variable 'watershed_temp' is used"
- "The PARFOR loop cannot run due to the way variable 'img_seg' is used"
- "Valid indices for 'watershed_temp' are restricted in PARFOR loops"
- "Valid indices for 'img_seg' are restricted in PARFOR loops"

How should I index these images for the code to work? Please help.

Thank you for any input in advance!

**Attempt**

```
function [bw_seg] = watershedImage(img, bw, param)

%% Parameters extraction
stats = regionprops(bw, img, 'Area', 'Image', 'PixelIdxList', 'BoundingBox');
param.medianarea = median([stats.Area]);

% Select only the BLOBs with sufficient area for watershed segmentation
thresh = 0.6*param.medianarea;                  % lower area threshold
BLOBind = find([stats.Area] > thresh);          % BLOB indices
boundingboxbuffer = 5;                          % in pixels
watershed_temp = false(size(img));
bw_seg = logical(bw);

%% Watershed on each individual binary section of the mask
parfor i = 1:length(BLOBind)

    % Extract each BLOB by cropping (with a buffer 'safety' border) the
    % bounding box of each BLOB
    r = round(stats(BLOBind(i)).BoundingBox);
    boundingboxBLOB = [max(r(1)-boundingboxbuffer,1) max(r(2)-boundingboxbuffer,1) ...
        r(3)+2*boundingboxbuffer-1 r(4)+2*boundingboxbuffer-1];
    img_BLOB = imcrop(img, boundingboxBLOB);

    % Crop the same region accordingly from the binary mask
    bw_BLOB = false(size(bw));
    bw_BLOB(stats(BLOBind(i)).PixelIdxList) = 1;
    bw_BLOB = imcrop(bw_BLOB, boundingboxBLOB);

    % Watershed segmentation (a written watershed segmentation algorithm)
    L = watershedBLOB(img_BLOB, bw_BLOB, param);

    %%%%%% I'm getting errors here for 'watershed_temp' and 'img_seg'!!! %%%%%%%
    if max(max(bwlabel(L))) > 0 && sum(sum(L)) >= 0.6*sum(sum(bw_BLOB))
        [f1, f2] = find(L > 0);
        fr = f1 + boundingboxBLOB(2) - 1;
        fc = f2 + boundingboxBLOB(1) - 1;
        watershed_temp(sub2ind(size(img), fr, fc)) = L(sub2ind(size(L), f1, f2));
        bw_seg(stats(BLOBind(i)).PixelIdxList) = 0;
    end

end

bw_seg = imfill(logical(bw_seg) | watershed_temp, 'holes');

end
```

Comment: Replace `parfor` with `for`. `parfor` doesn’t do what you apparently think it does. This is not a shared-memory parallelism, it is meant to spread computations across modes of a compute cluster. It can be used on a single computer, but that doesn’t change the way it works.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Initially, I had it working with `for`, but I want to rather use `parfor`. Any ideas how I can update the last code block of the loop when running with `parfor`?

Comment: As far as I understand, you cannot use `parfor` for this. And even if you could, it would not be efficient. Note that `parfor` sends data to other copies of MATLAB running on your desktop (or other nodes in the cluster), and then receives the results back. This communication is more expensive than the watershed computation.

Comment: You’re likely better off computing the watershed for the whole image at once. I don’t know what `watershedBLOB` is, so can’t give more help. Why not use the watershed function that comes with the Image Processing Toolbox (or any other library such as DIPimage)?

Comment: I actually am in the `watershedBLOB` - there I'm doing a multi-threshold-based watershed procedure utilizing the watershed function.

Comment: Then, is it possible to split the input image `img` and corresponding binary image `bw` into n (=workers) chunks, assign each chunk to each worker and let each worker go through the entire segmentation function `watershedImage` before finally merging the produced segmented binary images `bw_seg` together?